# Plot lines using vertices and faces in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot 2 circles with differents radius using matplotlib given their faces and vertices. This is my code to define the circles and to plot them.

```
r2,r3=2,3
n_t3=5
n_t2=n_t2
theta_t3=torch.linspace(0,2*torch.pi,n_t3,device=torchdeviceId)
VT3 = torch.stack((r3*torch.cos(theta_t3),r3*torch.sin(theta_t3)),dim=1)
theta_t2=torch.linspace(0,2*torch.pi,n_t2,device=torchdeviceId)
VT2 = torch.stack((r2*torch.cos(theta_t2),r2*torch.sin(theta_t2)),dim=1)
VT=torch.vstack((VT2,VT3))

FT3 = torch.cat((torch.arange(0,n_t3-1).reshape(n_t3-1,1),torch.arange(1,n_t3).reshape(n_t3-1,1)),dim=1)
FT2 = torch.cat((torch.arange(n_t3,n_t3+n_t2-1).reshape(n_t2-1,1),torch.arange(n_t3+1,n_t3+n_t2).reshape(n_t2-1,1)),dim=1)

FT=torch.vstack((FT2,FT3)).to(torchdeviceId)

xt, yt = (
    VT[FT,0].detach().cpu().numpy(),
    VT[FT,1].detach().cpu().numpy(),
)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xt,yt,label='target',marker='x',markersize=10,alpha=0.2,lw=10);
plt.show()
```

But i have this weird result where the two circles are linked even if there is no faces linking them in FT. [image: Plot of the circles]

Do you have any ideas what is the reason ?

Comment: 1. Combining the circle points will result in the circles being connected. 2. The plotting part of the code is also relevant here.

Comment: @jared but my faces are not connected when i define them. Yes sorry, i add the plotting part

Comment: Can you include the plotting of the lines? You just plotted the `x` markers.

Comment: i plot the lines this way. xt are couples of the x-coordinates of the same face and same for yt. This is my full code

Comment: You have two line colors so I would expect there to be two calls to the plot function.

Comment: @jared I don't understand why there are two colors neither.

Comment: I see why there are two colors, your `xt` and `yt` each have two columns. Anyways, each of those columns should only have 5 points (one for each corner and two of the first point to close the loop), yet you have 8. That's why the lines are going through more points than just their individual loops.

Comment: How would you modify the code then ? I don't see why this is a problem here.

Comment: Is the expected result to have nested diamonds?

Comment: Nested circles yes (i will run my code with more points when it will work)

Comment: Could not you just use circles as defined in matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html? Or use patches (more general)  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html

Comment: @YuliaV Circles are just an example here, i would like to deal with many differents shapes after

Comment: @Cantor - `patch` allows you to draw polygons (given their vertice coordinates) and it has many nice visual features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is plot the points to make a circle (rather than using matplotlib's patches), then you can just use your `VT2` and `VT3` tensors. (Note: I adjusted the aspect ratio to be a square, so when you add more points you will actually get a circle rather than an ellipse.)

```py
plt.figure()
plt.plot(*VT2.T, marker='x', markersize=10, alpha=0.2, lw=10)
plt.plot(*VT3.T, marker='x', markersize=10, alpha=0.2, lw=10)
plt.show()
```

If you want to set x and y variables:

```py
xt1, yt1 = VT2.T
xt2, yt2 = VT3.T

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xt1, yt1, marker='x', markersize=10, alpha=0.2, lw=10)
plt.plot(xt2, yt2, marker='x', markersize=10, alpha=0.2, lw=10)
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image]